# Nonetype object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I am trying to use an API wrapper downloaded from the net to get results from the new azure Bing API. I'm trying to implement it as per the instructions but getting the runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bingwrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    bingsearch.request("affirmative action")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bingsearch-0.1-py2.7.egg/bingsearch.py", line 8, in request
    return r.json['d']['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is the wrapper code:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%(query)s&$top=50&$format=json'
API_KEY = 'SECRET_API_KEY'

def request(query, **params):
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    return r.json['d']['results']
```

The instructions are:

```
>>> import bingsearch
>>> bingsearch.API_KEY='Your-Api-Key-Here'
>>> r = bingsearch.request("Python Software Foundation")
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r[0]['Description']
u'Python Software Foundation Home Page. The mission of the Python Software Foundation is to promote, protect, and advance the Python programming language, and to ...'
>>> r[0]['Url']
u'http://www.python.org/psf/
```

This is my code that uses the wrapper (as per the instructions):

```
import bingsearch
bingsearch.API_KEY='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'
r = bingsearch.request("affirmative+action")
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback, not just the error?

Comment: @isbadawi provided full traceback

Comment: What are the contents of `r` in the wrapper?

Comment: There's a slight difference between your calling code and the code that emitted the traceback (one uses the argument 'affirmative action' and the other uses 'affirmative+action'). Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this out myself, and it seems what you are missing is to properly url-encode your query. Without it, I was getting a 400 code.

```
import urllib2
import requests

# note the single quotes surrounding the query 
URL = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query='%(query)s'&$top=50&$format=json"

query = 'affirmative+action'

# query == 'affirmative%2Baction'
r = requests.get(URL % {'query': urllib2.quote(query)}, auth=('', API_KEY))
print r.json['d']['results']
```

Your example doesn't make much sense because your `request` wrapper returns a `list` of results, yet in your main usage example you are calling it and then checking a `status_code` attribute on the return value (which is the list). That attribute would be present on the response objects, but you don't return it from your wrapper.